# How to get document ID for a specific document?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to get the document id of a specific document when I put its name in a function.
Here is my function:

```
void _getId(town) {
var data = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('towns')
    .where('town_name', isEqualTo: town)
    .snapshots();
print(data.id);}
```

Here is my button:

```
ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => _getId(_townChosen), child: Text('Get ID')),
```

The value `_townChosen` is a string which corresponds to the field `town_name` in the database. In the complete program, I get the value from a dropdown button, this part works well.

Here is the [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsSZs.png)

All documents have an `town_name` field.
I need the id of the chosen town and send it in others widgets to use its subcollection. Please can you help me to get the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a variable called townid, and change your function to async, and use a stateful widget to update it, and use get instead of snapshots:

```
String townId = 'Get ID';

void _getId(town) async {
var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('towns')
    .where('town_name', isEqualTo: town)
    .get();
 setState(() {
      townId = data.docs[0].id; //because the query returns a list of docs, even if the result is 1 document. You need to access it using index[0].
    });
print(townId);
}
```

In your button:

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => _getId(_townChosen), child: Text(townId)),
```

Comment: Hi! That's working very well, thank a lot!